# How to get the value from image tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am tying to get value from an image (not src value) which is being clicked. I have tried val() , text() and html() with no luck. What is the correct way to do that ?

```
$("img[id*='silmex']").click(function(){
alert($(this).html());
});


<img id="silmex" value="265" src="./x.png" \>
<img id="silmex" value="845" src="./x.png" \>
<img id="silmex" value="698" src="./x.png" \>
```

Comment: [Image elements don't have a value attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element). Only form elements do.

Comment: Well "value" is not a standard attribute for `<img>` tags, but you should be able to get it with `$(this).attr("value")`.

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID

Comment: You should be using a `data-` attribute instead.

Comment: ... if you do switch to a `data-value` attribute, you'd fetch its value with `$(this).data("value")`

Comment: Please read the documentation before you use a specific function. `.text` and `.html` return the **inner content** as text (i.e. serialized child DON nodes). Since images don't have children, you don't even have to "try" these methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Pointy already pointed out, "value" is not a standard attribute for image tags.

Using the HTML5 data attributes woul probably be a cleaner solution.

```
<img class="silmex" data-value="265" src="./x.png" />
```

you can then access these data attributes using

```
$(this).data('value');
```

Answer (score 4):

Using this your problem will be solved

```
$(this).attr("value")
```

But considering that `img` tags doesn't have a value attribute, you can use `data-attributes` introduced in HTML5.

Like bellow

```
<img id="silmex" data-value="265" src="./x.png" \>
<img id="silmex" data-value="845" src="./x.png" \>
<img id="silmex" data-value="698" src="./x.png" \>


$("img[id*='silmex']").click(function(){
   alert($(this).data('value'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/60/)

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all attribute of HTML element with the jQuery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method like :

```
$("img[id*='silmex']").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

But "value" isn't a valid attribute for HTML, so use data- information, and the good jquery method : [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
<img id="silmex" data-value="265" src="./x.png" \>

$("img[id*='silmex']").click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Comment: You aren't using the `attr()` method. This is an exact copy of his code.

Comment: sorry, i miss something